# How to keep a fixed size pool of ListenableFutures?

Tags: java, concurrency, guava, future

I am reading a large file of Urls and do requests to a service. The request are executed by a client that returns `ListenableFuture`. Now I want to keep a pool of `ListenableFuture`s, e.g. have `N` Futures being executed concurrently in maximum.

The problem I see is that I have no control over the `ExecutorService` the `ListenableFuture`s are executed in because of the third-party library. Otherwise I would just create a `FixedSizePool` and create my own `Callable`s.

1) A naïve implementation would be to spawn `N` Futures and then use `AllAsList` which would satisfy the fixed size criteria but makes all wait for the slowest request.
Out of order processing is ok.

2) A slightly better naïve option would be to use the first idea and combine it with a rate limiter, by setting `N` and `rate` in a way that the amount of concurrent requests is in good approximation to the desired pool size. But I am actually not looking for a way to a Throttle the calls, e.g. using `RateLimiter`.

3) A last option would be to spawn `N` Futures and have a Callback that spawns a new one. This satisfies the criteria of a fixed size and minimizes the idle time, but there I don't know how to detect the end if my program, i.e. close the file.

4) A non-`ListenableFuture`-related approach would be to just `.get()` the result directly and deal with the embarrassly parallel tasks by creating a simple `Threadpool`.

For knowing the job queue is empty i.e. closing the file I am thinking of using a `CountdownLatch`. Which should work for many options.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.  How do you feel about just using a `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`?

```
Semaphore gate = new Semaphore(10);
Runnable release = gate::release; // java 8 syntax.
Iterator<URL> work = ...;
while(work.hasNext() && gate.acquire()) {
  ListenableFuture f = ThirdPartyLibrary.doWork(work.next());
  f.addListener( release, MoreExecutors.sameThreadExecutor() );
}
```

You could add other listeners maybe by using `Futures.addCallback(ListenableFuture, FutureCallback)` to do something with the results, as long as you're careful to `release()` on both success and error.

It might work.

Comment: Thanks. I implemented this option and it works ok. However the code looks a bit messy now due to other limitations in having to rely on the ListenableFuture carrying all the context.

Answer (score 0):

Your option 3 sounds reasonable. If you want to cleanly detect when all requests have completed, one simple approach is to create a new `SettableFuture` to represent completion.

When your callback tries to take the next request from the queue, and finds it to be empty, you can call `set()` on the future to notify anything that's waiting for all requests to complete. Propagating exceptions from the individual request futures is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks. I added my idea about how to solve synchronization using a `CountdownLatch` and added an idea about a fourth approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FixedSizePool` for embarrassedly parallel tasks and `.get()` the future's result immediately.

This simplifies the code and allows each worker to have modifiable context.